# PHP code not removing the < and > tags

Tags: php

My PHP code, is supposed to remove < and > because its displayed on the website from the database and to prevent scamming

```
<?php
$acc_music = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['acc_music']);

function strip_tags_content($text, $tags = '', $invert = FALSE) { 

  preg_match_all('/<(.+?)[\s]*\/?[\s]*>/si', trim($tags), $tags); 
  $tags = array_unique($tags[1]); 

  if(is_array($tags) AND count($tags) > 0) { 
    if($invert == FALSE) { 
      return preg_replace('@<(?!(?:'. implode('|', $tags) .')\b)(\w+)\b.*?>.*?</\1>@si', '', $text); 
    } 
    else { 
      return preg_replace('@<('. implode('|', $tags) .')\b.*?>.*?</\1>@si', '', $text); 
    } 
  } 
  elseif($invert == FALSE) { 
    return preg_replace('@<(\w+)\b.*?>.*?</\1>@si', '', $text); 
  } 
  return $text; 
}

mysql_query("UPDATE users SET youtube_embed = '".strip_tags_content($acc_music)."' WHERE id = '" . $_SESSION['user']['id'] . "'")or die(mysql_error());
?>
```

The acc_music output is being put in the Database but NOT removing the < and > tags.

Comment: @rjdown does not seem to me that this act as htmlspecialchars

Comment: @rjdown htmlspecialchars: '<' to '&lt;', not '<' to ''

Comment: Please can post an example of original text / desired transformation? Your code appears as `strip_tags` function, but your question appear as ` <a> ` => ` a `

Comment: @rjdown I think the "prevent scamming" is mainly meant as preventing a `<script>` injection or something similar. This is clearly a youtube embed link being stripped down to its raw URL - which I don't think the asker should be criticized for. It's a good thing to allow embed URLs for ease of use, and to prevent `<script>` attacks and other attacks of that nature.

Using `htmlspecialchars` absolutely is **not** anything even in the same realm as this. He doesn't want to replace `<` with `&lt;`, *clearly*.

Comment: Next time, use PDO `prepare` statement. It prevents from malicious sql input(not html input) automatically. Also, use `htmlspecialchars` to output, not to input!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `strip_tags_content()` is not setup to remove the actual greater than / less than symbols. It appears to only be setup to strip text within the actual tag itself, leaving the symbols themselves.

Either change your regex, or just throw this before `return $text`:

```
$text = str_replace( array('<', '>'), '', $text);
```

Or better yet, replace

```
return $text;
```

With

```
return str_replace( array('<', '>'), '', $text);
```